# Spring Netflix Eureka Server starts at intelliJ with illegal URL

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I started an app with spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server. At startup, it runs into an `java.net.URISyntaxException`. 
I only added `@EnableEurekaServer` after start.spring.io-bootstrap.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaserverApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(EurekaserverApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Pom

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>eurekaserver</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>eurekaserver</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

    </project>
```

With and without properties

```
spring.application.name=discovery-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761
```

Stacktrace

```
2019-01-13 16:23:45.089  INFO 1199 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bc96212] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.2.RELEASE)

2019-01-13 16:23:45.175  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.e.e.EurekaserverApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-13 16:23:45.746  WARN 1199 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2019-01-13 16:23:45.914  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=4c4401f4-0661-370e-9753-ebccd4312969
2019-01-13 16:23:45.989  INFO 1199 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9bc96212] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-01-13 16:23:46.240  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-01-13 16:23:46.257  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-13 16:23:46.257  INFO 1199 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-13 16:23:46.262  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/mb/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-01-13 16:23:46.331  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-13 16:23:46.332  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1147 ms
2019-01-13 16:23:46.422  WARN 1199 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-01-13 16:23:46.422  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-01-13 16:23:46.434  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@716e431d
2019-01-13 16:23:46.976  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2019-01-13 16:23:47.034  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-01-13 16:23:47.036  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-01-13 16:23:47.150  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-01-13 16:23:47.150  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-01-13 16:23:47.434  WARN 1199 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2019-01-13 16:23:47.435  WARN 1199 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-01-13 16:23:47.435  INFO 1199 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-01-13 16:23:47.598  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-13 16:23:48.005  WARN 1199 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
2019-01-13 16:23:48.007  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-13 16:23:48.009  INFO 1199 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-13 16:23:48.026  INFO 1199 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-13 16:23:48.041 ERROR 1199 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at com.example.eurekaserver.EurekaserverApplication.main(EurekaserverApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1424) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1315) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/simple/SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573.simpleDiscoveryProperties(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.simpleDiscoveryClient(SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573.CGLIB$simpleDiscoveryClient$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4a0f91c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573.simpleDiscoveryClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryProperties]: Factory method 'simpleDiscoveryProperties' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.simpleDiscoveryProperties(SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573.CGLIB$simpleDiscoveryProperties$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4a0f91c.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$94ce2573.simpleDiscoveryProperties(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-commons-2.1.0.RC2.jar:2.1.0.RC2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://Gersee my company:8080
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3186) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3097) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 72 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

We can see the problem: The server tries to start with the url `http://Gersee my company:8080`. Why didn't start it simple at `localhost`? How can I fix it?
If I run a spring-boot-webapp with a controller without eureka, it starts at localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it gets wrong hostname from yout host file.

Class `SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration` creates bean `SimpleDiscoveryProperties` where host is set.

```
@Bean
public SimpleDiscoveryProperties simpleDiscoveryProperties() {
    SimpleDiscoveryProperties simple = new SimpleDiscoveryProperties();
    simple.getLocal().setServiceId(this.serviceId);
    simple.getLocal()
            .setUri(URI.create(
                    "http://" + this.inet.findFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo().getHostname()
                            + ":" + findPort()));
    return simple;
}
```

Method `findFirstNonLoopbackHostInfo()` provides the hostname.
You can provide your bean and set the hostname according to your preference.
I don't know if there is any simpler method to do that.

Edit:

You can try to ignore wrong picked interface with `spring.cloud.inetutils.ignoredInterfaces` property.
Or just set `eureka.instance.hostname` to `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The problem was that my host file had a docker and government settings associated with localhost 127.0.0.1